# Three.js rotate vector and screen edge detection

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js

I have a vector that I'm trying to keep length but rotate 90deg on colliding with the screen edge, but it gives me a weird out effect… don't know what I can be doing worn but it happens when I try to apply a Matrix and a Euler transform… Also for the screen detection, what I have is okj for detecting on and off screen, but it would be handy to know if it's the bottom, top, righ or left edge… Any clues? Thanks!

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3(-0.2, -0.2, 0);
var a = new THREE.Euler( (Math.PI/2), 0, 0, 'XYZ' );
direction.applyEuler(a);
```

For the collision; I'm using the following:

```
camera.updateMatrixWorld(); // make sure the camera matrix is updated
camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld );
cameraViewProjectionMatrix.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
frustum.setFromMatrix( cameraViewProjectionMatrix );

console.log(frustum.intersectsObject(textMesh));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the line to get the reversed camera projection matrix.

The screen edges effectively became an object "outside" my `view frustum`, with whom my objects can now actively collide. By being now a negative view frustum, everything but that which we see is a 'walled object' that confines the frustum itself.